# Polar form of quadratic equations

Tags: polar-coordinates, quadratic-forms

I'm trying to derive a polar, general and graphing, form of a quadratic equation. Here Is what I've done so far.

$$
f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
$$
And
$$
f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k
$$
Then I substituted $$ x=r\cos(\theta) $$ and $$ y=r\sin(\theta) $$
Here's the work:
$$r\sin(\theta)=a(r\cos(\theta)^2+b(r\cos(\theta)+c $$
$$ r\sin(\theta)=ar^2\cos^2(\theta)+br\cos(\theta)+c $$
$$ \sin(\theta)=\arccos^2(\theta)+b\cos(\theta)+\frac{c}{r} $$
$$\frac{\sin(\theta)-b\cos(\theta)-c}{\arccos^2(\theta)}=r $$
$$ r(\theta)=\frac{1}{a}\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)-\frac{b}{a}\sec(\theta)-\frac{c}{a}\sec^2(\theta) $$
This seems to work for any quadratic where $c=0$. But if $c$ is not equal to zero, then the graph goes from a parabola to some craziness. The same is true using the graphing form I derived through the same process $$ r(\theta)=\frac{1}{a}(\tan(\theta)+k\sec(\theta)+2h)+h^2\sec(\theta) $$

Does anyone know how to fix this so that it will properly graph quadratics where $c$ is not equal to zero?

Comment: i love this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you treated $c/r$ as $cr$ when you factored out $r$.
Instead, use the quadratic formula for $r$:

$$ rsin(\theta)=ar^2cos^2(\theta)+brcos(\theta)+c $$

which becomes
$$ 0=ar^2cos^2(\theta)+brcos(\theta)-rsin(\theta)+c $$

which becomes 
$$r=(1/2a)\sec^2(\theta)\left(\sin(\theta)-b\cos(\theta) \pm \sqrt{(\sin(\theta)-b\cos(\theta))^2-4ac \cos^2(\theta)}\right)$$

Note this reduces to your equation for $c=0$,and should also be simple for a focus at the origin.

Edit: A wolfram Alpha plot for a=b=c=1: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3d(1%2f2)%5csec%5e2(%5ctheta)(%5csin(%5ctheta)-%5ccos(%5ctheta)+%2b%5csqrt%7b(%5csin(%5ctheta)-%5ccos(%5ctheta))%5e2-4+%5ccos%5e2(%5ctheta)%7d)+polar

Comment: one thing though, how did you break down the second equation in order to plug it into the quadratic formula? I'm trying to make sense of it but it im not sure what you let a, b, and c equal... (a, b, and c, being the variables in [(-b)(+/-)sqrt(b^2-4ac)]/(2a)

Comment: I had $a=a\cos^2(\theta),b=b\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta),c=c$.

Comment: Thanks that's what i guessed.